# selecting augmented path in ford fulkerson algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ford-fulkerson

If there are many augmented paths in the residual network for a given flow network, what path should I take at the first to find the bottleneck capacity?

Answer (score -1):

The Ford-Fulkerson method does not specify which alternating path to use if there is more than one.

But you can modify the algorithm such that,

Goal:  choose augmenting paths so that:

- Can find augmenting paths efficiently.
- Few iterations.

Edmonds-Karp (1972) analyzed two natural heuristics for choosing the augmenting path. Choose the augmenting path with,

- **Largest bottleneck value. (fat path)  - Greedy Algorithm Fewest**
- **Number of arcs. (shortest path, can find using BFS)**

Comment: what do you mean by few iterations? Is it possible to have cycles in a augmenting path.